# Comparing Old vs New Value of an Account throws "Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, Account (48:27) -Trigger Handler Class

Tags: apex, trigger

Learning Apex here. I am trying to get this issue resolved where in I have moved the comparing logic to check if the billing city has got changed and if so do something with related contacts of that account.

My trigger handler class is

```java
public static void updateContactBillingAddressNewWay(Map<Id,Account> OldMap, Map<Id,Account> NewMap){
    Set<Id> accIdsThatGotBillingAddressChangedNewWay = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account Acc: newMap.values()){
        **if(OldMap.get(Acc.BillingCity != NewMap.get(Acc.BillingCity))){**
            accIdsThatGotBillingAddressChangedNewWay.add(Acc.Id);
        }
    }
    
    // Query all contacts of the accounts that got their billing address changed.
    List<Account> accWithContacts = [SELECT id,name,BillingCity,(SELECT id, name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id in: accIdsThatGotBillingAddressChangedNewWay];
    List<Contact> conListToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    for(Account acc: accWithContacts){
        List<Contact> consOfTheLoopedAccount = acc.Contacts;
        for(Contact con : consOfTheLoopedAccount){
            con.MailingCity = acc.BillingCity;
            conListToUpdate.add(con);
        }
    }
    if(conListToUpdate.size() > 0)
        update conListToUpdate;
}
```

It throws error saying

> Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, Account (48:27)

Can I get some guidance on how to compare in trigger handler class?

Trigger

```java
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
     AccountTriggerHandler.updateContactBillingAddressNewWay(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
}
```

Comment: Separate from the issue in your querstion. You do not need to check if a list is empty before performing DML on it. Salesforce is smart enough to handle that situation automatically. Also, a common "code style" is to have variable names start with lower case letters (so `OldMap` and `NewMap` should be `oldMap` and `newMap`). I would advise to _never_ omit curly braces for `for`, `if`, `else if`, or `else`. Field names in queries should have a space after the comma. Whatever code style you use, the most important thing is _to be consistent_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Map` data type has two parts to it, the *key* and the *value*. In your case the key is an `Id` (specifically an *account id* here), and the value is the `Account`.

When using a map, you give it the key (the Id), and it returns the value associated with that key (the Account).

So this is wrong
`OldMap.get(Acc.BillingCity != NewMap.get(Acc.BillingCity))`

And proper syntax would be
`OldMap.get(Acc.Id).BillingCity != NewMap.get(Acc.Id).BillingCity`

Almost all programming languages evaluate things in left-to-right order. The thing to realize here is that lines of code with multiple "things" in them get partially evaluated before the next "thing" is evaluated.

To illustrate, in pseudocode...

```
// Start
OldMap.get(Acc.Id).BillingCity != NewMap.get(Acc.Id).BillingCity

// Step 1, evaluate OldMap.get(), given an Account Id
// results in an Account
<The old Account>.BillingCity != NewMap.get(Acc.Id).BillingCity

// Step 1.5
// Account has a BillingCity field, so <The old Account>.BillingCity is
//   valid syntax

// Step 2, we see the != operator
// We've only evaluated one side of the operator
// We need to continue evaluating before we can resolve this operator

// Step 3, evaluate NewMap.get(), given an Account Id
// results in an Account
<The old Account's BillingCity> != <The new Account>.BillingCity

// Step 3.5
// Account has a BillingCity field, so <The new Account>.BillingCity is
//   valid syntax

// Step 4, now we can evaluate the != operator
// The thing on the left is a string
// The thing on the right is a string
// These two types can be compared together
// The result is a boolean
<The old Account's BillingCity> != <The new Account's BillingCity>
```

Since you're looping over the values in `NewMap` though, you don't need to do `NewMap.get(Acc.Id).BillingCity`. You can just use Acc directly, and replace that bit with `Acc.BillingCity`.

So the final form of this `if` statement would be
`if(OldMap.get(Acc.Id).BillingCity != Acc.BillingCity)`

Comment: Thanks @Derek F for coding format suggestions. Really helpful as beginner.